# Creating incremental backup with tar - --listed-incremental -g

Tags: bash, backup, tar

I have problem with the tar linux program. I would like to create a incremental backup. I use following tar command for the first full backup:

```
tar --create --gzip --listed-incremental=$SAVEDIR/backup.snar --file=$SAVEDIR/$DATE.tar.gz $EXCLUDE $DIRECTORY
```

`$EXCLUDE` contains for example `"--exclude test/testdir --exclude test/testdir2"`
`$DIRECTORY` contains `"-C /Users/user1/Desktop/ test"`

If I execute the command I get following error:

```
tar: Option --listed-incremental=/Users/hofmeister/Desktop/test/backup.snar is not supported
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar –help
```

If I change the `--listed-incremental` option to `-g =$SAVEDIR/backup.snar`. I get:

```
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
```

What went wrong?
I use following version of tar: `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`

The problem is the tar version which is bsd. With macports you could install gnutar. Here everything works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using `bsdtar`, and not the gnu `tar`.  `bsdtar` doesn't support incremental  backups.  They have slightly different flags too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I installed the gnu tar with macports. Now everything works fine.